# MonoGame and Kinectv2 .Net 4.5 compatibility issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, monogame, kinect-sdk

When I create a project(`Window Game`) in `MonoGame 3.2` and include reference of `kinectv2` I found this error.

How to resolve it?

> **Error** 2   The type or namespace name 'Kinect' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Anas\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\GameName1\GameName1\Game1.cs    10  17  GameName1
>
> **Warning**   1   The primary reference "Microsoft.Kinect, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built
>   against the ".NETFramework,Version=**v4.5**" framework. This is a
>   higher version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=**v4.0**". GameName1

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project in Visual Studio, select "Properties", then change the "Target Framework" to ".NET Framework 4.5".